# Why are SIGTRAP and SIGILL thrown when adding and removing breakpoints in CodeBlocks with GDB?

Tags: gdb, codeblocks, gnu-toolchain

I am using CodeBlocks 17.12 <s>bundled</s> with MingGW: GDB 7.11.1, mingw32-gcc 5.1.0, and mingw32-g++ 5.1.0.

When setting a breakpoint while the program is running I get a SIGTRAP signal. I am able to continue past the breakpoint and hit it multiple times. When I remove the breakpoint, the program still stops on the same line with a SIGTRAP. On the next continue it stops with a SIGILL and I am no longer able to continue.

Breakpoint is set on line 9, the cout line:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 65000; i++)
    {
        cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Debugger Output in CodeBlocks:

```
Trying to interrupt process with pid: 19600; child pid: 19600 gdb pid: 20264
Continuing...
Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
At C:\Users\twalczak\Desktop\test\main.cpp:9
Continuing...
At C:\Users\twalczak\Desktop\test\main.cpp:9
Continuing...
At C:\Users\twalczak\Desktop\test\main.cpp:9
Continuing...
At C:\Users\twalczak\Desktop\test\main.cpp:9
Continuing...
At C:\Users\twalczak\Desktop\test\main.cpp:9
Continuing...
At C:\Users\twalczak\Desktop\test\main.cpp:9
PC register is not available                   <-- 'Breakpoint removed at this point'
Continuing...
Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
At C:\Users\twalczak\Desktop\test\main.cpp:9
Continuing...
Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
At C:\Users\twalczak\Desktop\test\main.cpp:9
```

**EDIT** Removed bundled because I was using a custom MinGW install, not the bundled install.

Answer (score 0):

I got past this issue by pointing CodeBlocks to use the MinGW install it was bundled with at

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW
```

instead of my install at

```
C:\MinGW
```